# restrict or_where to a specific where between 2 wheres in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, where-clause

I have this code:

```
    $this->db->where('status',1);
    $this->db->where('category',$category_id);
    $this->db->or_where('parent_category',$category_id);
    $this->db->or_where('grandParent_category',$category_id);
    $this->db->or_where('parentOfGP_category',$category_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('posts');
```

The problem is the first where gets overridden and it get also the ones who has 0 and 2 status because of the next or_wheres instead I want the or_wheres to be just for the where('category',$category_id); and not for status

Is there a way to do this in codeigniter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly pass in your query instead of using Active Records as:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT name, title, email FROM my_table');
```

Also, if you want to be sure what exactly is being formed out of your Active Record query above, use the following method:

```
echo ($this->db->last_query());
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bit more complex cause you want to connect `AND` and `OR` conditions. Have a look here: [Codeigniter Doku](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where#query-grouping)

So for your case it should be something like this:

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('posts')
  ->group_start()
    ->where('category', $category_id)
    ->or_group_start()
      ->where('parent_category', $category_id)
    ->group_end()
    ->or_group_start()
      ->where('grandParent_category', $category_id);
    ->group_end()
    ->or_group_start()
      ->where('parentOfGP_category', $category_id);
    ->group_end()
  ->group_end()
  ->where('status', 1)
->get();
```

This code is not tested. You may need to adjust some stuff.